# StringTokenizer questions

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I am facing some problems in String tokenizer like if I code is following then there are some questions which I want to know.

**Code**:

```
public class Str_Tokenizer {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer("this is him");
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            System.out.println(st.nextToken());
        }
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. If I don't use the `while(st.hasMoreTokens())` then how I can use `StringTokenizer`?
2. If I don't use `st.nextToken`, what I should use?

Comment: why "not use" exactly?

Comment: You can switch to python :)

Comment: you may use hasMoreElements() instead? Or put it a for loop?

Comment: @pimpf0r `hasMoreElements` Returns the same value as the `hasMoreTokens` method :)

Comment: yeah, I know :) But I thought you were looking for alternatives, maybe you didn't like the wording or so.

Answer (score 0):

> [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons

First you cannot use  that class without those `hasMoreTokens()`  and `next()` method.

You cannot loop on it as a alternative because `hasMoreElements()` Returns the same value as the `hasMoreTokens` method. `nextElement()` Returns the same value as the `nextToken` method  and you don't want to use them.

**other wise `hasMoreElements` and `nextElement`  are alternatives.**

> Although its use is **discouraged** in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Even [docs of StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) given example how you can avoid to use it

The following example illustrates how the String.split method can be used to break up a string into its basic tokens:

```
 String[] result = "this is a test".split("\\s");
 for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
     System.out.println(result[x]);
```

Comment: *First you cannot use that class without those hasMoreTokens() and next() method* - I completely disagree on this. You can use `hasMoreElements()` and `nextElement()`. Or you can get the token count using `countTokens()`, put it in a `for` and use `nextElement()` in it.

Comment: @R.J  `hasMoreElements()`
Returns the same value as the `hasMoreTokens` method. `nextElement()`
Returns the same value as the `nextToken` method. OP don't want to use those method's. Thanks for pointing though.

Comment: He just wants to know an alternative, I guess. Ofcourse, he would want to be access the next value one way or the other. Anyways revoking my `-1` after your edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `while` and `nextToken`, go for String split.
 this way:

```
String s ="this is him";
        String[] s2 = s.split(" ");
        for (String str : s2) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```